# C# Sending CTRL+C keyboard input to Word

Tags: c#, keyboard, ms-office, sendkeys

I'm currently practicing hotkeys and writing a small background app that instantly googles the selected text on the ctrl+shift+alt+N hotkey.

It all works very well. I register the global HK, I intercept the message via WndProc() etc.

What does not work is the way I'm trying to copy the selected text in the currently focused window by sending it a CTRL+C keyboard input.

Here is my current method, in a nutshell:

```
IntPtr fWin = GetForegroundWindow();
SetForegroundWindow(fWin);

//InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.CONTROL, VirtualKeyCode.VK_C);
SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)"); //I tried both ways, with the InputSimulator lib, and the standard SendKeys. None work.

Thread.Sleep(1000); //I wait a little bit for the clipboard to get the text.

Console.WriteLine(Clipboard.GetText()); //This is where I get disappointed...

Process.Start("firefox.exe", "-new-tab http://www.google.com/search?q=" + Clipboard.GetText().Replace(" ", "%20"));
```

This method works for some applications only (like the one we use in the office: Trados Studio which is quite the complex text management software). However, I'm **unable to make it work with applications like Word, Outlook or Notepad**.

Believe it or not, I'm able to send them letters like this:

```
string txt = "Y U NO WORK?";
SendWait(txt);
//OR
InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry(txt);
```

But when it comes up to CTRL+C, **nothing happens**.

Do you guys have an idea of what's going on? I hope there isn't some MS restrictions on this one... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you are sending the hot-key event for the clipboard copy method, why not simply monitor the clipboard instead and have the user press the ctrl-c?

Comment: Because I don't want to trigger the search everytime the clipboard text content changes. I need it to happen only when the user presses the hotkey I defined.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to help you directly but may I suggest that you read about OLE/COM.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z074ky.aspx

I know that you can use this to accesses word, excel etc from other applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help Uri. I found the solution. It was about timing. The hotkey for my app overlapped the CTRL+C command of the target application. So in fact, Word, notepad etc. were handling a hotkey they did not understand. I added some code to check that my user released the hotkeys before running the copy process.

Comment: Alex, I'd suggest automating Office applications instead. The way you chose is not stable and reliable. You can get an instance of the running application and then get the required information. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, yes, it would work for sure, but Office applications are not the only ones we are using. I basically need to retrieve any selected text within any application that allows copy via CTRL+C. It's been a week since we're using my current version and no one complained (yet) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to make sure that the keys were resolved and released before sending CTRL+C input to the focused application to avoid Hotkey overlap. Otherwise, the focused application is sent a messed up HK that it doesn't understand or handles weirdly.
It would explain why Word inserted a date or inserted character "i" or copyright instead of copying to clipboard.

Hope it makes sense!